# Group By on Column A and calculate value count on column B in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to know about a query where I can perform a group by on Column A and can calculate the count of the values in column B and create a new table from it.
Column A and B have limited types of values. (Categories)

Table:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | X |
| b | Y |
| a | X |
| a | Z |
| b | Z |
| a | X |

Result:

|  | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| b | 0 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: what have you done before?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: You can use FILTER() https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES and https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is PIVOT type query. Converting row value to column.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT A ""
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN B = 'X' THEN 1 END) "X"
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN B = 'Y' THEN 1 END) "Y"
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN B = 'Z' THEN 1 END) "Z"
FROM test
GROUP BY A
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33f2f4bcf423dccf7c79d6a8b2d64197

Use FILTER clause

```
-- PostgreSQL (v11)
SELECT A " "
     , COUNT(B) FILTER (WHERE B = 'X') "X"
     , COUNT(B) FILTER (WHERE B = 'Y') "Y"
     , COUNT(B) FILTER (WHERE B = 'Z') "Z"
FROM test
GROUP BY A
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=fec763cb0e5fed99b96e055dd587a235

Comment: The trick here is you know the possible values in `B`. If you don't know what might be in B, you have to use dynamic SQL.